# SQLite order by dd:mm

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by

In my sqlite database, birthdays are stored in a string field like: 11-09
I want to order the birthdays but it only looks at the first 2 numbers, I tried:

```
sql.all('SELECT id,user,date FROM birthdays ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 4').then(rows => {
```

how can I make it so that it looks at both day and month?

Comment: Please provide sample data, result you get and result you expect. HIN: Store Dates in a date Format not as string

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using either a DATE or a DATETIME column for storing birthdays instead. You will have to deal with the date in terms of Unix Time in the rest of your application, but it should simplify dealing with the dates in the long run. Your query would not change from what you have there as well.

Comment: The only choices I have are: INT, TEXT, BLOB, REAL, NUMERIC

Comment: Sorry, my experienced is with MySQL. Unix time as defined back in 1970 uses a signed 32 bit integer. You could specify your date column as an integer (and limit it's size to 32 bits if you liked) to achieve the same effect as what I described as a DATETIME column above.

Comment: could you help me out with the new query if I change it to integer?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this dialect, but the query you have to fetch the birthdays should work just the same with int dates. Changing to int would be two operations as far as I can tell: ALTER TABLE birthdays DROP COLUMN date; and ALTER TABLE birthdays ADD COLUMN date INT;